# Covering Space Examples

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

In my algebraic topology course we briefly discussed automorphism groups of covering spaces before moving onto deformation retracts. In passing, my professor mentioned that it is easy to come up with covering spaces of $S^1 \vee S^1$ whose automorphism group is $\mathbb{Z}_3, \mathbb{Z}_6$, $D_4$, and $A_4$.

After some thought, I was able to come up with (i.e. draw covering spaces of $S_1 \vee S_1$ having automorphism groups isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3, \mathbb{Z}_6$ and $D_4$. However, after several days of trying, I have been unable to give an example of a covering space of $S^1 \vee S^1$ whose automorphism is group is isomorphic to $A_4$.

How should I go about finding such an example? Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Find two elements of $A_4$ which generate it.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown If I'm not mistaken, $A_4$ is generated by $(123)$ and $(12)(34)$. However, I don't see how this helps to construct the desired covering space.

Comment: This represents $A_4$ as a quotient of the free Abelian group on two generators, and that is the fundamental group of $S^1\vee S^1$.

Comment: Unfortunately, covering spaces were only briefly discussed so I do not see how this helps me construct such a covering space for $S^1 \vee S^1$. I think I am missing a major result that was not given in the lecture. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: @ImNotThereRightNow_ A key phrase to know here is "Cayley graph".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has left the forum.